# parsing html comments correctly

Tags: html, parsing

Is there a good reference on how to parse html comments robustly especially 
where the html contains javascript which could break the comment

for example:

```
         <!--
         <script type="text/javascript">
         for( var i = 10; i > 0; i-- ) {
                      if( myar[i].status > 3 ) {
                                   ntlp++;
                      }
         }
         </script>
         -->
```

the two minus's and the greater than 3 in the script could be considered
a concatenation that is interpreted as '-->' ( if you follow the html/sgml spec
correctly ).

Anyway, is there a list of rules/gotchas to process all this ? 
In C would be preferable, otherwise pseudo-code is great too.

thanks

Ashod

Comment: Yes, *use an HTML parser* :) See the HTML specification for the parsing rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you meet `<!--` in the code, everything further is a comment until `-->`. What other rules are needed?

Comment: That's not correct.. The rules are:
<! starts the tag
-- first occurance of double dash means to consider the next '>' as part of the comment
-- next occurance of double dash means next '>' closes the tag
keep alternating rules as double dashes occur

Comment: @AshodApakian Who told you that?

Comment: I do not believe this is true. I am pretty sure that `<!--` *cannot* start an HTML comment inside a CDATA block (e.g. `script`), for instance. As such, I think `-->` may also be *protected*. (And thus it *was* used as a hack in Netscape version 3.0 and such.) In any case, citing the HTML *specification* would make (or break) this answer.

Comment: @suddnely_me - OK, what happens if the script for any reason contains this sequence of characters: `--!>` ?

Comment: That's exactly, what got me thinking.. I'm trying to look for the spec, that described this issue..